# as.Date() function for %m/%Y (e.g. 04/2020) format

Tags: r, date, formatting, as.date

My df has a date column with month/year dates written like 04/2020. I am trying the as.Date() function to get the right class (because it is a character now) but it only leaves me with NA output. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste` a day and then `as.Date` should work as 'Date' include day as well

```
as.Date(paste0(df$date, "/01"), "%m/%Y/%d")
```

---

Or convert to `yearmon` class with `as.yearmon` (from `zoo`) and wrap with `as.Date`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(df$date, "%m/%Y"))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("04/2020", "05/2020"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

NOTE: From `R 4.0.0`, by default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: Thank you for the extremely quick answer, that was helpful! Answer accepted!